# How can I check for only numeric input and return greatest number?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build this small function to take three numeric input, check for only numeric one,  and return the greatest one.

```
var x = prompt("Enter a Value","0");
var y = prompt("Enter a Value", "0");
var z = prompt("Enter a Value", "0");
var num1 = parseInt(x,10);
var num2 = parseInt(y,10);
var num3 = parseInt(z,10);

function checkNum(num1, num2, num3) {
    if ( (typeof x == 'number') && (typeof y == 'number') && (typeof y == 'number') ) }

function highestNum(num1, num2, num3){
    var highest = Math.max(num1, num2, num3);
    return highest;
    {
      console.log(highestNum(num1,num2,num3));
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, you are trying and...?

Comment: And your question is..?

Comment: What's the problem? Is your your code crashing? Is it not returning the values you expect?

Comment: So, what does this code do?  Does it work?  Do you see any errors?  Do you get the correct results?

Comment: Looking at your code - your brackets do not appear to match - is this a copy and paste error - or is the code accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just have some structural problems with your code:

```
var x = prompt("Enter a Value","0");
var y = prompt("Enter a Value", "0");
var z = prompt("Enter a Value", "0");
var num1 = parseInt(x,10);
var num2 = parseInt(y,10);
var num3 = parseInt(z,10);
alert(Math.max(num1, num2, num3));
```

This works and is tested at http://jsfiddle.net/harveyramer/c7tkD/

Comment: Thanks very much, as you can see! I'm a newbie in JS world,

Comment: I  was fighting this piece of codding for a while now. So parseInt check for numeric input so I don't need the function checkNum, is that right? Thanks again.

Comment: @procrastinator, yes, I just stepped out the office for a minute, I had no idea that people will step in so fast to help me. Now I know.

Comment: Yes, checkNum is redundant in this case.

Comment: Thank you @procrastinator, I have edited the answer to remove the redundant function call.

Answer (score -1):

```
var x = prompt("Enter a Value","0");
var y = prompt("Enter a Value", "0");
var z = prompt("Enter a Value", "0");
var num1 = parseInt(x,10);
var num2 = parseInt(y,10);
var num3 = parseInt(z,10);
function checkNum(num1, num2, num3) {
    if ( (typeof x == 'number') && (typeof y == 'number') && (typeof y == 'number') );
}
function highestNum(num1, num2, num3) {
    var highest = Math.max(num1, num2, num3);
    return highest;
}
console.log(highestNum(num1,num2,num3));
```

Cleaned up your code for you, the problem was a missing semicolon and unexpected brackets.
Now works perfectly.